# Google Calendar api v3 re-update issue

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm working on google calendar and having problem with syncing data between my Calendar app on Iphone to Google Calendar. (I use google api v3)
The problem is: I can update an event by code just 1 time after i created it. The next time when i try to update it, i get message code 400: bad request.

We can use google calendar explore to test this (https://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=calendar&_v=v3&_m=calendars.update) by creating an event then update it 2 time.

Does any one meet this problem?

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem and got the answer here: [Google Calendar API v3 - Update Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332255/google-calendar-api-v3-update-event)

You can edit the same event twice, you just have to 'get' the event sequence

```
$event = $service->events->get("primary", $exist);

$seq=$event['sequence'];
```

and use `$event->setSequence($seq)`

when setting your update event details.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot update the same event twice. Instead, base your second update request on the new event data that is passed to the callback in the first update call (which has a new eTag) to update it the second time.

Comment: hey, i'm facing the same issue when working with  google-api-ruby-client. Do you know how to send etag with request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332255/google-calendar-api-v3-update-event

Comment: +1 This solved the same problem I was having in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Java code example on how to update using sequence:

```
Event updatedEvent; 
Calendar Service;   

updatedEvent.setSequence(Service.events().get(mCalendarId, updatedEvent.getId()).execute().getSequence());
Service.events().update(mCalendarId, updatedEvent.getId(), updatedEvent).execute();
```